# How to reference a library between multiple projects

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libraries

If I have several android libraries that I want to use among multiple projects, how can I set up my apps to utilize these libraries without having to make local copies?  Using the Import Module option in android studio will always copy the project locally, and changes made to the original library will not be reflected in my project unless I copy it over again, which is not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of Android Studio 1.0.2 this is not an option within the normal UI.  It can be achieved however by manually changing your settings.gradle file within each app you would like to reference your libraries from.  If I have a library I would like to reference, open the settings.gradle file and add the following lines:

```
include ':app', ':MyLibrary'
project(':MyLibrary').projectDir = new File(settingsDir, '../../Libraries/MyLibrary')
```

This would assume a project structure like so:

```
/Apps
    /MyApp
        /app
            ...code files
        settings.gradle
/Libraries
    /MyLibrary
        ...code files
```

The settingsDir variable refers to the directory the settings.gradle is found in, this will ensure others pulling down your repo will still be able to resolve the relative path.

With the extra line in your settings.gradle file you will be able to edit the library from the UI as if it was copied local, but be able to share that code among many projects.  To add the library as a reference, simply go to module settings --> dependencies --> add.

Answer (score 0):

The above answer makes so much sense but i have applied a little editing to it work on my apps.
Copy your library folder into the folder where there is the app folder then pen the settings.gradle and edit it to something like this

```
include ':app', ':mylibrary'
```

Then open the build.gradle of the application then goto dependencies and add your library to it as follows :

```
compile project(':mylibrary')
```

You can try this